# {exp:low_search:form}

Tags: search, low-search, low

Probably a obvious answer, apologies in advance!

We're running EE v2.8.1 and LOW Search 3.4.0.

In some instances we want to be able to search entries but ONLY return results where a particular field is NOT empty...

Is there a way to do this within the {exp:low_search:form} param_value OR with a hidden field?

For example I assumed these would work but do not appear to, first using a hidden field:

```
{exp:low_search:form}
    <input type="hidden" name="search:my_field" value="not IS_EMPTY" >
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

or as a param_value:

```
{exp:low_search:form search:my_field="not IS_EMPTY"}
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="search:my_field" value="not IS_EMPTY" >
```

This actually works, I'm sure I tested this?!

More. Coffee. Required.